# Find the nearest neighbour / latitude and longitude

Tags: java, sql, latitude-longitude, nearest-neighbor

I have a table (DB2 database) with city information and corresponding latitude and longitude and many other info related to the city. My requirement is:

Input to my application will be latitude and longitude which may or many not be exact lat and long stored in DB. I need to find the nearest City info from the table with the help of input latitude and longitude. Any help is highly appreciated.

Is there a nearest neighbor implementation in java available for this
or
SQL to handle this

Answer (score 2):

You could use a KD-Tree:

[KDTree Implementation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253767/kdtree-implementation-in-java)

Within SQL, you could Pythagoras to find, and then order by, the distance from a given point, but this likely wouldn't be very efficient.