# intellij not finding maven imports from third party repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, import

My pom.xml includes

```
    <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spantus</id>
        <name>spantus sourceforge</name>
        <url>http://spantus.sourceforge.net/maven/global/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaml</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

My code includes the line

```
    net.sf.javaml.core.Instance instance;
```

with error

> cannot resolve symbol 'net'

(Similarly, imports fail).

Yet mvn package works fine, which indicates it's compiling and finding the dependency. Furthermore the pom.xml shows no error on the dependency.

I've manually navigated the source in version 0.1.5 to make sure the package name for the import is correct. (But mvn compiles it anyway, so no matter).

I have done "invalidate cache and restart" and the error persists."

How can I get intellij to work?

Answer (score 2):

Including this dependency worked for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaml</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Without setting any repository.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @besil, thanks for your answer. I used this and maven can't find the dependency. What are your default repositories?

Comment: nevermind... I don't know why, but it's working right now :)

Comment: well, this is strange... =)