# Efficient searching algorithm for finding closest point to a line segment

Tags: java, algorithm, google-maps, quadtree, r-tree

I have list of points (latitude & longitude) from google API call. Every 5sec interval, I am getting current location of the vehicle. My task is to check if the vehicle has not deviated from the defined path and within permitted tolerance of 100m.

```
DirectionsResult results = DirectionsApi.getDirections(context, "Source Address", "Destination Address")
                             .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING).await();
 List<LatLng> latLngList = results.routes[0].overviewPolyline.decodePath();
```

Below is my logic to prepare line segment and calculate the distance between line segment and the current location using **Haversine formula**. This is working fine if the **latLngList** size is less. But, if the size is more its taking long time to give the result.

```
LatLng current = new LatLng(12.95847371672292,77.67890810966492);
for (int i=0; i < latLngList.size()-1; i++) {
    double tolerance = LocationUtil.distanceToLineSegment(latLngList.get(i), 
            latLngList.get(i+1), current);
    if(tolerance < 100){
        message = "Vehicle within permitted tolerance of 100m.";
        break;
    }
}
```

List latLngList =  Arrays.asList("12.950980000000001,77.69407000000001","12.951440000000002,77.69417","12.951480000000002,77.69398000000001","12.951550000000001,77.69380000000001","12.951920000000001,77.69387","12.95212,77.69392","12.95217,77.69388000000001","12.95226,77.69348000000001","12.95231,77.69299000000001","12.952580000000001,77.69305","12.952710000000002,77.69303000000001","12.95279,77.69303000000001","12.95293,77.69309000000001","12.95312,77.69318000000001","12.95334,77.69324","12.95354,77.69339000000001","12.953740000000002,77.69348000000001","12.95381,77.69354000000001","12.95387,77.69364","12.954020000000002,77.69371000000001","12.954160000000002,77.69375000000001","12.95466,77.69376000000001","12.95536,77.69382","12.955570000000002,77.69382","12.955960000000001,77.69389000000001","12.956130000000002,77.69384000000001","12.95612,77.69378","12.955910000000001,77.69271","12.955770000000001,77.69177","12.95573,77.69149","12.955330000000002,77.68949","12.95513,77.68824000000001","12.95503,77.68780000000001","12.954960000000002,77.68728","12.954920000000001,77.68688","12.95471,77.68451","12.954500000000001,77.68231","12.95437,77.68066","12.954400000000001,77.68033000000001","12.954450000000001,77.68001000000001","12.954500000000001,77.67986","12.9547,77.67941","12.955010000000001,77.67874","12.956660000000001,77.67534","12.95715,77.67434","12.957600000000001,77.67317000000001","12.957720000000002,77.67281000000001","12.95781,77.67225","12.957860000000002,77.67190000000001","12.95795,77.67098","12.958,77.67043000000001","12.958050000000002,77.66938","12.95809,77.66865","12.95808,77.66799","12.95814,77.66704","12.958240000000002,77.66639","12.958440000000001,77.66556","12.958570000000002,77.66498","12.958620000000002,77.66463","12.95889,77.66354000000001","12.959050000000001,77.66276","12.95916,77.66222","12.95926,77.66142","12.959270000000002,77.66111000000001","12.959190000000001,77.66057","12.959040000000002,77.65978000000001","12.95903,77.65926","12.959080000000002,77.65837","12.95916,77.65768000000001","12.959190000000001,77.65745000000001","12.95921,77.65722000000001","12.959280000000001,77.6558","12.95931,77.65489000000001","12.95936,77.65365000000001","12.95939,77.65318","12.95949,77.65144000000001","12.95964,77.64983000000001","12.95968,77.64942","12.95982,77.64837","12.960070000000002,77.64599000000001","12.96025,77.64456000000001","12.96039,77.6431","12.96044,77.64275","12.96052,77.64193","12.960360000000001,77.64173000000001","12.960030000000001,77.64163","12.95983,77.64159000000001","12.959600000000002,77.64156000000001","12.958950000000002,77.64152","12.958450000000001,77.64149","12.958290000000002,77.64145","12.958240000000002,77.64142000000001","12.958150000000002,77.64141000000001","12.95803,77.6414","12.957820000000002,77.64138000000001","12.95733,77.64139","12.956710000000001,77.64143","12.955890000000002,77.64142000000001","12.95471,77.64137000000001","12.954690000000001,77.64223000000001","12.95471,77.6423","12.954690000000001,77.64237","12.95462,77.64240000000001","12.954080000000001,77.64254000000001","12.95404,77.64256","12.953990000000001,77.64263000000001","12.95391,77.64279","12.953360000000002,77.64264");

```
**Searching nearest neighbor for point: "12.95847371672292,77.67890810966492"**
```

Linear Search Output: (12.955010000000001,77.67874)

KDTree Search Output: (12.956660000000001,77.67534)

Have tried **KDTree** & **QuadTree** but not found the suitable implementation for the problem. Can any one have implementation or any other searching mechanism which is suitable for this scenario. Experts please help.

Comment: A k-d tree seems to be the right tool for the job. Is your problem that you don't know how to implement a k-d tree, or is your problem that you don't know how to use a k-d tree to solve the task?

Comment: @frececroka I am searching for a k-d tree implementation which suits my requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KDTree Implementation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253767/kdtree-implementation-in-java)

Comment: @frececroka I am getting different co-ordinate while searching using KDTree algorithm. I have updated my input latlng list and search input. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't have enough information to see why you get the wrong results. Maybe ask a new question with an exact description of how you're using the k-d tree to solve your problem so people can help.

Comment: Also note that it is definitely not enough to just search for the nearest vertex of the path. A point can be very far away from all vertices and still be very close to (the middle of a) line segment.

Comment: A simple solution that may very well be good enough is to discretize every line segment into multiple points. Then you can use a plain k-d tree to locate the closest of the discretized points, which won't be much farther away than the closest line segment.